# How to change date picker dialog OK / Cancel button colors in android

Tags: kotlin

I'm facing this error. I can't see OK / Cancel buttons because these text color are white. How can I change these text colors in Kotlin . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImUJt.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImUJt.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to look in DatePicker documentation?  [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/DatePicker.md)

Comment: Please add code, what have you tried so far?